# how to get string array from response in nsurlconnction (of wcf web srvice)?

Tags: ios, arrays, xml, nsurlconnection, response

I created wcf soap service, which contains one method and it returns string array...

I call that service in ios(in xcode objective c) application, but it returns the response as xml.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><IMethodNameResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

how can i get string array from response result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options here.

First one is to parse that XML with `NSXMLParser`. You need to know XML structure and create object for each XML document. This object must implement `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol.

Another one is to use XPath to get exactly what you want from XML document. Here is [XPath example](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html). This doesn't require any third-party libraries to include in your project but if you OK with third-party, you could check this library and tutorial [XML Tutorial for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml).

And the last option is WCF itself. You could try to switch to JSON in WCF.